# Email link seems to be just text from Nexus 7 (OS ver: 4.2.2)

Tags: java, android, email, html-email

In my application i have an option to send the url of files through email and it works fine in all devices except nexus 7 (OS version 4.2.2 only). When mail from nexus 7, the recipient gets only a text.I have searched for many solutions and could not find any.
Below is my code

```
public static boolean sendEmailLink(Context context, String[] emailTo, String[] emailCC, String[] emailBCC, String subject, String emailBody, String notification) throws ActivityNotFoundException {

    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailTo);

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, emailCC);

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, emailBCC);

    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailBody));

    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, notification));

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Little difference but maybe it helps. You can try this other Intent constructor

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:" + destination));
```

It works for me, here's the complete method I use:

```
public static void sendMail(Activity activity, String subject, String body, String destination) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:" + destination));
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,BusinessName);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder().append(BusinessName+ "<br /><br />"+ LongDesc+ "<br /><br />"+ "<a href=\""+ ShareURL+ "\">"+ ShareURL+ "</a>").toString()));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me :( . the issue is only with os version 4.2.2

Comment: Yeah did u check this with 4.2.2?

Comment: I have tested it with nexus prime 4.2.2 and it works for  me ,but in nexus 7 its not working .did u try with nexus 7 ?

Comment: I found the issue only in the gmail application of the nexus 7 device ,and it works fine in all other mail clients(yahoo,hotmail etc)